# Create a DataFrame of combinations for each group with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The inputs are as follows.

```python
Out[178]: 
  group value
0     A     a
1     A     b
2     A     c
3     A     d
4     B     c
5     C     d
6     C     e
7     C     a
```

For this input, I want to create a combination for each group and create one DataFrame. How can I do it?

The output I want to get:

```python
Out[180]: 
  group  0  1
0     A  a  b
1     A  a  c
2     A  a  d
3     A  b  c
4     A  b  d
5     A  c  d
0     C  d  e
1     C  d  a
2     C  e  a
```

Comment: why din't you accept the answer that was 14 times faster then then answer you accepted?

Comment: @Pizzalord `.apply` is a familiar function for many users. I decided to accept it as a typical answer. Since the faster answer has tricky elements, so I think that users interested in it should refer to it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `combinations` in a comprehension

```
from itertools import combinations

pd.DataFrame([
    [n, x, y]
    for n, g in df.groupby('group').value
    for x, y in combinations(g, 2)
], columns=['group', 0, 1])

  group  0  1
0     A  a  b
1     A  a  c
2     A  a  d
3     A  b  c
4     A  b  d
5     A  c  d
6     C  d  e
7     C  d  a
8     C  e  a
```

Comment: This answer was 14 times faster than the answer using `.apply`. It is a good answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with lambda function and [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from  itertools import combinations

df = (df.groupby('group')['value'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(x,2))))
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  group  0  1
0     A  a  b
1     A  a  c
2     A  a  d
3     A  b  c
4     A  b  d
5     A  c  d
6     C  d  e
7     C  d  a
8     C  e  a
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with `itertools` and a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

gen = ([(g,)+i for i in list(combinations(df.loc[df['group'] == g, 'value'], 2))] \
               for g in df['group'].unique())

df_out = pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(gen)), columns=['group', 0, 1])
```

**Result**

```
  group  0  1
0     A  a  b
1     A  a  c
2     A  a  d
3     A  b  c
4     A  b  d
5     A  c  d
6     C  d  e
7     C  d  a
8     C  e  a
```